# Not able to run the sqlcmd due to incorrect syntax

Tags: bash, shell, sqlcmd

I am trying to run the sqlcmd in a bash script, however it's giving syntax error as it's not able to cast the column -

```
sqlcmd -S $DB_HOST  -U $DB_USER -P $DB_PASSWORD -o $mssqlresult -s ","  -W -h -1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT * FROM prod_UDD.prod_UDD_CDD.V_DAILY_CTS_TRX WHERE CAST("/""UTC DATE TIME"/"" AS DATE)='$trade_date';"
```

Below error is coming up

```
Sqlcmd: 'DATE" "TIME/ AS DATE)='2021-01-31';': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: There's something wrong with your escaping. Check the result of the argument to `CAST`.

Comment: That's what I am not able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape character is `\`, not `/`.

Rewrite your command like this:

```
sqlcmd -S "$DB_HOST" -U "$DB_USER" -P "$DB_PASSWORD" -o "$mssqlresult" -s ","  -W -h -1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT * FROM prod_UDD.prod_UDD_CDD.V_DAILY_CTS_TRX WHERE CAST(\"UTC DATE TIME\" AS DATE)='$trade_date';"
```

Note 1: that I also put your shell variables inside double quotes; not quoting a shell variable [should be the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32674809/7233423).

Note 2: shouldn't there be back-quotes around `UTC DATE TIME` rather than double quotes? My feeling is that `UTC DATE TIME` is a column name, not a string. If I'm right, try this instead:

```
sqlcmd -S "$DB_HOST" -U "$DB_USER" -P "$DB_PASSWORD" -o "$mssqlresult" -s ","  -W -h -1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT * FROM prod_UDD.prod_UDD_CDD.V_DAILY_CTS_TRX WHERE CAST(\`UTC DATE TIME\` AS DATE)='$trade_date';"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I tried the above and now it's getting another error for Incorrect syntax near '`'.

Comment: It's giving error --- Incorrect syntax near '`'.